# Laravel 5.0 - change redirect when login fails

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, redirect, controller

I'm using Laravel 5.0 built-in authentication controllers, and in the AuthController I have 2 variables:

```
protected $redirectTo = '/';
protected $redirectAfterLogout = '/';
```

Is there any variable which would redirect to a specific page if and only if the login failed? If not, how should I do it?

Answer (score -2):

Please putt bellow method in your controller

```
public function authenticate(Request $request)
    {
        if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $request->input('email'), 'password' => $request->input('password')]))
        {
            return redirect()->intended('dashboard');
        } else {
           return redirect('your-path-to-redirect');
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

I know this question is old but I will publish my answer because it can be useful for someone in the future.

When authentication fails, they will be redirected to the **/auth/login** URI by default. If you want to modify this just add a **loginPath property** on the AuthController and set your own path:

```
protected $loginPath = '/your-path';
```

You can find more information in [Authentication Laravel Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/authentication)

Hope this helps!